# What is a feeder uplink/downlink?

Tags: cubesat, communication-satellite

I'm trying to understand the terminology used in the specifications of several satellite systems, such as those outlined on pages 9-11 [here](http://www.its.bldrdoc.gov/media/30335/red_s.pdf).

I'm guessing a mobile uplink/downlink is RF uplink and downlink that can communicate with mobile phones, but I can't find anything in my searches that defines feeder downlink.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Mobile uplink/downlink are channels between the satellite and 'end users': mobile satphones, satcom terminals on ships, aircraft etc.
- Feeder uplink/downlink are channels between the satellite and a ground station. The ground station is connected to terrestrial phone/data networks.

When a satphone user calls someone who uses a 'normal' landline, the call is routed from the satphone to the satellite (through the mobile up/downlink), then from the satellite to a ground station (through the feeder up/downlink), and the ground station connects the call to the landline phone network.

Usually, a satellite has many mobile links, and one feeder link. The satellite bundles the data from all mobile links into the one feeder link.

Answer (score 0):

Feeder link is from the Gateway to the satellite
Check the image [on Slide#3](http://csivc.csi.cuny.edu/engsci/files/ens466/ENS466_P2.pdf) of the link